# Unresolved reference when using inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, inheritance, linker-errors

How can I get the template definition into a seperate header files?

My code compiles when it is included in a single main.cpp.

**maip.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

template<class T1, class T2>
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual T1 f1();
    virtual T2 f2();
};

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 Base<T1, T2>::f1() {return T1();}
template<class T1, class T2>
T2 Base<T1, T2>::f2() {return T2();}

class Derived : public Base<int, int> {
public:
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i;
    Derived d;
    i = d.f1();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I break it up I get unresolved external symbols:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "Base.h"
#include "Derived.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i;
    Derived d;
    i = d.f1();
    return 0;
}
```

**Base.h**

```
#pragma once

template<class T1, class T2>
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual T1 f1();
    virtual T2 f2();
};

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 Base<T1, T2>::f1() {return T1();}
template<class T1, class T2>
T2 Base<T1, T2>::f2() {return T2();}
```

**Derived.h**

```
#pragma once

class Derived : public Base<int, int> {
public:
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};
```

This results in:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Base::Base(void)"
>   (??0?$Base@HH@@QAE@XZ) referenced in
>   function "public: __thiscall
>   Derived::Derived(void)"
>   (??0Derived@@QAE@XZ)

Comment: minor point: `Derived.h` should include `Base.h` since it inherits from `Base`, it's awkward to ask clients to include the files in a precise order, therefore each header should be self-sufficient (ie should compile without anything included before it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't provide an implementation for `Base`'s constructor. Try adding

```
template<class T1, class T2>
Base<T1, T2>::Base () { }
```

Alternatively, you can remove its declaration from your second code snippet. (It is also not present in your first code example).

Your linker basically says that `Derived::Derived ()` tries to call `Base::Base ()`, which you explicitly declared, but he can't locate an implementation for it.